# How to set value 0 (zero) in input?

Tags: forms, input, null, form-submit

I made ​​a simple form to arrange the structure of the html code.
I got a problem when I want to make the number 0 in the input tag value without clear it after submit.
value on this input can be changed, but I want to set the default to be 0 = This will be 0px;
as an example -> style="padding: px px px px" it is the wrong structure, this should be -> style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px"

I make the value to be like this.
this will prevent the value lost after submitted.
how do i give value 0, but does not remove this feature?
//Edited, It just a simple for example://

```
    <?php
    echo "style='padding:".$ul_padding_top.$ul_pd_px." ".$ul_padding_right.$ul_pd_px." ".$ul_padding_bottom.$ul_pd_px." ".$ul_padding_left.$ul_pd_px.";'";
    ?>

    <form action="/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ul_padding_top" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['ul_padding_top']) ? $_POST['ul_padding_top'] : '' ?>" />px = padding-top<br/>
<input type="text" name="ul_padding_right" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['ul_padding_right']) ? $_POST['ul_padding_right'] : '' ?>" />px = padding-right<br/>
<input type="text" name="ul_padding_bottom" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['ul_padding_bottom']) ? $_POST['ul_padding_bottom'] : '' ?>" />px = padding-bottom<br/>
<input type="text" name="ul_padding_left" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['ul_padding_left']) ? $_POST['ul_padding_left'] : '' ?>" />px = padding-left<br/>
<input class="foo_ul_pd" type="hidden" name="ul_pd_px" value="px" <?php if(isset($_POST['ul_pd_px'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> padding value "px"<br/>


    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Generate!">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please show the code that handles these actions.

Comment: I've replaced with a more complete script code

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for

```
<input class="foo" type="checkbox" name="padding" checked />
```

Or you could use Jquery

```
$('.foo').prop('checked',true);
```

And to read it with Jquery can do

```
$('.foo').prop('checked');
```

**EDIT:**

Just re-read your description you say you wish to put the value 0 in a field you will need to change `type="checkbox"` to `type="text"` at which point you can do `value="0"`

EDIT 2:

This won't work

```
<input class="foo_ul_pd" type="hidden" name="ul_pd_px" value="px" <?php if(isset($_POST['ul_pd_px'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
```

a input `type="hidden"` is basically a `type="text"` so you would just need to use

```
 <input class="foo_ul_pd" type="hidden" name="ul_pd_px" value="0" />
```

Comment: Hi AbstractChaos, thanks for your answer.. <input type="hidden" name="ul_pd_px" ... is working.. I call it for display text "px", and I do not want this check box visible on the page.. <br/> s

Comment: <input class="foo" type="checkbox" name="padding" checked /> yes it is standar input tag, but after I submit value will be empty.. how to set this default value to 0? and when I submit, this value will not be clear..